# How to sort array with selected list in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have a list look like:

```
const initArray = [
  {
    id: 0,
  },
  {
    id: 1,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
  },
];
```

A selected list look like:

```
const selectedList = [
  {
    id: 2,
  },
];
```

And the desired data has been sorted:

```
const outPut= [
  {
    id: 2,
  },
  {
    id: 0,
  },
  {
    id: 1,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
  },
];
```

I'm in trouble right now, so I can't figure it out yet.

Can you share some solutions?

Comment: If you want to move one item to the front of the array, you first need to find the index of the item using `Array#findIndex`; you can use `Array#splice` to remove that item from the array, and `Array#unshift` to push it onto the front of the array.

Comment: does the objects share the same object reference (with same `id`)? what have you tried?

Comment: Do you want to sort by the selectedList,then sort by id?

Comment: thank you so much, especially @BenAston.

Comment: @flyingfox no, I just want sort selectedList on the top.

Comment: @NinaScholz with the same. but I think Ben's answer is optimal.

Comment: If you have big data, and it's sortable, then you will be able to achieve better than O(N) for the algorithm because you will be able to apply a binary chop to exponentially reduce the search space.

Comment: @BenAston I think I need it can be run first, then find another way to optimize later :)))))
tks you.

Comment: @Zuet I think findIndex will be O(N), splice O(1), and unshift O(1). Array will be backed by a linked list or similar. If `selectedList` is expected to contain more than one element then the time complexity will be O(N<sup>2</sup>). Maybe this is what you were driving at. If `initArray` is sorted, then using binary search the find step can be `log(N)` and the overall complexity `N * log(N)`. I welcome correction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take an object which keeps the order of the first objects and sort the rest after.

```js
const
    data = [{ id: 0 }, { id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }],
    selectedList = [{ id: 2 }],
    order = Object.fromEntries(selectedList.map(({ id }, i) => [id, i + 1]));

data.sort((a, b) => (order[a.id] || Number.MAX_VALUE) - (order[b.id] || Number.MAX_VALUE));

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

- Using [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), get set of ids to prioritize
- Using [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), sort the items using the above set

```js
const _sort = (arr = [], selected = []) => {
  const priority = new Set( selected.map(({ id }) => id) );
  return [...arr].sort(({ id: a }, { id: b }) => priority.has(b) - priority.has(a));
}

const 
  initArray = [ { id: 0 }, { id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 } ],
  selectedList = [ { id: 2 } ];
console.log( _sort(initArray, selectedList) );
```